# Does a new Date Object in java contain the current date? Or is it empty?

Tags: java, date

Date now = new Date();

```
    if (now.getTime() - leasedDate.getTime() > 21 * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
        throw new TooLate();
    leased.remove(x);
```

I'm looking at some code examples and above is a part of it. There's something I don't understand. Does the date object called "now" have the current date and hour in it? Because I thought it should be empty when it's initialised so I don't understand how now.getTime() can work.

Thanks!

Comment: You have the source *and* the documentation....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Date` object contains a long which represents the time in milliseconds since 1970. The default constructor initialised it from `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Answer (score 11):

Quote from Java Docs - `new Date() - Allocates a Date object and initializes it so that it represents the time at which it was allocated, measured to the nearest millisecond.`

So the answer to your question is: **Yes, it contains the current date**.

Answer (score 1):

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date()

Yes it does.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```
Date now = new Date();
```

contains the current system time (the exact time of the object creation in RAM).